# Porque existe FloatToStr se o Delphi não possui o tipo de dado Float?

Tags: delphi, tipagem, pascal

Lendo sobre os tipos de dados do Delphi/Pascal percebi que não existe o tipo `Float`, porém, existe a função `FloatToStr()`, assim como `StrToFloat()`.

Neste caso, poderia utilizar variável de ponto flutuante de qualquer tipo e a função se encarrega de realizar a conversão corretamente?

Comment: Exatamente, qualquer tipo de ponto flutuante será convertido.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem programador que tem dificuldade de nomear coisas. Na verdade é meio normal entre as pessoas em geral, tem até uma citação que as duas coisas mais difíceis da computação é invalidar cache e nomear coisas.

Não posso falar qual o motivo de terem feito isso, mas pra mim é só uma forma de tentar dar um nome só pra várias coisas e tornar a função mais descobrível tendo algumas sobrecargas.

De fato o que ela faz é trabalhar com vários tipos que possuem parte decimal, com ponto flutuante, ou não, o que é bem engraçado :)

[Documentação do Free Pascal](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/floattostr.html).

Outra coisa curiosa é que a função que cria um tipo de ponto flutuante é única, o que mostra que quem fez não estava pensando muito bem no problema. [Documentação](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/strtofloat.html).